# How to specify minimum type dependency version in TS library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

### Overview

In my TypeScript setup I have a library (`mylibrary`) and a consumer of the library (`consumer`). Both have a dependency to `react` and therefore a dependency to `@types/react`. `mylibrary` has a direct dependency to `react`. The `consumer` has a dependency to `react` through its `react-router` dependency.

The minimal requirement of `mylibrary` is `@types/react` `^16.8.0` while the minimal requirement for `react-router`'s `@types/react` is `*`.

### Expected result

The `@types/react` dependency gets resolved to `^16.8.0`. (When executing `yarn` in the `consumer`)

### Actual result

The `@types/react` dependency gets resolved to `16.4.14`.

### Question

How can I properly specify the minimal required `@types/react` version to `^16.8.0` in `mylibrary` in order to get this version of `@types/react` resolved in the `consumer`?

### Attachments

package.json `consumer`

```
"dependencies": {
  "react-router": "4.3.1", 
  "@types/react-router": "4.4.4", (has a dependency on @types/react: *)
  "mylibrary": "5.0.8" (has a dependency on @types/react: ^16.8.0)
}
```

package.json `mylibrary`

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.8.3",
  "@types/react": "^16.8.0"
}
```

$yarn why @types/react

```
=> Found "@types/react@16.4.14"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "@types#react-router" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "@types#react-router#@types#react"
```

yarn.lock

```
"@types/react-router@*", "@types/react-router@4.4.4":
  version "4.4.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react-router/-/react-router-4.4.4.tgz#4dbd5588ea6024e0c04519bd8aabe74c0a2b77e5"
  integrity sha512-TZVfpT6nvUv/lbho/nRtckEtgkhspOQr3qxrnpXixwgQRKKyg5PvDfNKc8Uend/p/Pi70614VCmC0NPAKWF+0g==
  dependencies:
    "@types/history" "*"
    "@types/react" "*"

"@types/react@*":
  version "16.4.14"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react/-/react-16.4.14.tgz#47c604c8e46ed674bbdf4aabf82b34b9041c6a04"
  integrity sha512-Gh8irag2dbZ2K6vPn+S8+LNrULuG3zlCgJjVUrvuiUK7waw9d9CFk2A/tZFyGhcMDUyO7tznbx1ZasqlAGjHxA==
  dependencies:
    "@types/prop-types" "*"
    csstype "^2.2.0"
```

Comment: *The @types/react dependency gets resolved to 16.4.4* - for which package? If there's 16.4.4 somewhere, mylibrary should get its own 16.8.0 copy. It's consumer's responsibility to specify correct @types/react dependency if it needs it.

Comment: Unfortunately there can't be a second version of `@types/react` since it is declaring global types which result in subsequent declaration errors. If I understand you correctly defining every single peer type dependency doesn't sound like a proper solution as well.

Comment: If some dependency has @types/react@16.4.4 dependency, it will be installed. Otherwise it's impossible for 16.4.4 to appear from nowhere, unless there's a bug in Yarn. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Comment: I added the yarn.lock to the question. It's actually .14 not .4.

Comment: Did you try to remove a lock? From what you posted it's still unclear where that 16.4.4 came from. Any way, if it's React project (and I guess it is), it should have its own react and @types/react dependencies that will unambiguously specify version constraints.

Comment: Mh, yes. It was a locking issue. :/ 16.4.14 was the first @types/react version that was locked for this project. I unlocked it now by updating the yarn.lock and everything is fine. Thx a lot for your help :)